# org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource

Tags: sql, jdbc, datasource, classcastexception

Trying to connect to a (local) SQL database using jTDS JDBC drivers.

*JAVA CODE*

```
private JtdsDataSource dataSource = null;

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException {
        ...
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (JtdsDataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/postcodes");
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                ...
    }
```

*CONTEXT.XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/postcodes" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="user" 
              password="pass"
              driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource"
              url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/AUSPostcodes"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              maxActive="10" 
              maxIdle="4"/>
</Context>
```

When I run this on tomcat, get the following error....

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource
```

Would appreciate some help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't give you access to a `JtdsDataSource` directly. It only uses that datasource to populate its internal DBCP datasource. When you use JNDI to ask for a datasource, you get the DBCP datasource.

BTW: There is (usually) no reason why you would cast to any other interface than `javax.sql.DataSource`. The solution therefor is to cast to that interface (`javax.sql.DataSource`).